# Storing Documents on Cloud safety concerns

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage

I am in the process of scanning and storing all my important documents on a cloud drive.

For example OneDrive. My question is how safe is this. There are lots of contradictory on the web about the safety.

I want to know how close this can get to safety of me scan and store documents on a

Hard drive and then Detach and store the hard drive.

Storing on cloud is more streamlined and I prefer it but safety concerns stops me.

Also any other proper storing suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Using cloud storage is like using a VPN... It just moves the point of trust... Do you trust your cloud storage provider? It will always be safer to host and store them yourself, but there is a level of convenience having them stored in the cloud... There is always the possibility of a data breach with cloud storage, but there is if you host it yourself as well... The point is you need decide on your own comfort level with using cloud storage, no one can give you a definitive answer that it is or isn't "safe".

Comment: There are cloud services which offer to encrypt your files, how reliable that encryption, is based on the reliability of the service provider. It's possible to mount a VHDD and encrypt the contents using VeraCrypt or BitLocker, provided you keep the size of the VHDD, below the allowed file size for the service.  You can also just encrypt the data on your HDD, synchronize the files to the cloud, and the files would be encrypted.  Questions seeking service and software suggestions are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: If safety from loss is a concern, store *both* in the cloud and at home.  If security from others obtaining your documents is a priority, then how can you guarantee the cloud storage provider cannot be hacked?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I did encrypt a folder on my windows. So if someone steal it , they cannot read the file???